# File exists vs. File does not exist. Is there a difference in performance?

Tags: programming-practices, code-quality, optimization

Let's say I am checking a directory for the existence of a file, and then depending on whether or not the file exists, I act accordingly. For example, see the two Python snippets below.

```
if os.path.isfile(file_name):
    # do task A
else:
    # do task B
```

or

```
if not os.path.isfile(file_name):
    # do task B
else:
    # do task A
```

Is there a difference between the two or is it just semantics? While the example I gave uses Python, would the rules apply the same to other languages?

Comment: Both are potentially race conditions if task A or B involves acting on the file. The file may appear/disappear between checking the `if` condition and executing either task. Generally you proceed with task A as if the file is there and handle the exception if it turns out to not be there. File I/O is a form of concurrency and you should assume that things can change between any two program statements.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491 See also: **[Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/165773)**

Comment: @Doval - your comment could be a really great answer.

Comment: The second form might be semantically used to denote a guard clause: http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is considered to be best practice to arrange the condition such that it is most probable to be entering your if clause.  The <50% condition should be your else clause.  In this instance,  it depends on what you're expecting.  If you expect to find the file, then you should use `if os.path.isfile(file_name):`.

This reason stems back to optimization of branching, though nowadays the difference is so subtle that unless performance were very important, you wouldn't do it to optimize but rather to provide a convention to the programmer that this is the expected behavior.

Another reason you may want to switch the if and else clauses is if you're being forced to awkwardly word your condition.  An example of this is if you already have `isNotOpen`, and you want to check the more probable condition that `isNotOpen` is false, then it would be ugly to write `if not isNotOpen:`.  One solution could be to switch the if and the else clause and just write `if isNotOpen:`, though I think in such circumstances, it would be better still to name variables according to the condition you expect to be true.  In other words, you wouldn't have a variable named `isNotOpen`, but rather `isOpen`.  When you hit the if statement, your most probable condition is not the negated variable but the variable itself, so `if isOpen:` which both ensures that it is readable and that the most probable condition is in the if clause.

In this respect, there are those that would not add "not" in the name at all, though I don't have a problem with this so long as it is a condition you're expecting (and hence you won't ever have to test the *negation* of that condition).

I think that other than this, there is no reason why you should do one over the other, however I would expect (expect in this context being a loose term) the more probable condition to be in the if clause in any language, not only in Python.  But that's just my 10 cents.

Comment: Lots of people would argue that the best practice is to avoid negation in conditionals since it's easier for humans. That's a much stronger reason than a micro-optimization like that, which probably isn't one since I doubt the branch predictor cares if you flip the statements one way or the other.

Comment: There are potential minuscule performance differences depending on how which side of the branch is treated as default... **in machine code**. But machine code layout is not just compiler business, it may vary within one compiler based on countless heuristics and hints (`__builtin_assume`). It's not something that most programmers even *can* be concerned with (no way to predict how the machine code will be organized), regardless of how tiny the difference is. I don't know how good this reason *used* to be but by now it's a long-dead unicorn so I wouldn't even *mention* that ever existed.

Comment: @delnan The reason behind doing it this way was once very much real.  Although that's not really true now, that has also been the cause of the convention of putting the more probable condition first, so I don't think it is *irrelevant*.

Comment: @Doval You make a good point.  I'll make a point of it in my answer.

Answer (score 9):

There is 0 difference. However, there are some guidelines about what you put in the if and what - in the else.

One is that you should try to put a "positive" result in the if. Many languages have shorter negation than " not " (Java has "!" that shouldn't have whitespace around it), and it's easy to overlook them, especially if you're looking at a verbose method name right next to it.

Another is that you should put the expected result first, and unexpected later.

A third one I can remember off the top of my head is that if one of the branches allow you to terminate early - put that first and the rest of the code outside an if whatsoever. (I seem to recall there also being one that is the direct opposite of this...)

**TL;DR:**
No difference to compiler. Only convention and readability.

Comment: The third case (early termination) is called "guard clause".

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's easier for people to understand the conditional without the negation - it's one less thing to think about when deciphering the meaning of the condition. The performance difference will probably be negligible, and worrying about it is premature optimization. (Besides, if you're working in Python, this kind of micro-optimization is worthless; if you really had a performance problem, you'd solve it by using better algorithms or implementing the critical code in C.)

However, in this case both of your options are potentially race conditions if task A or B involves acting on the file. The file may appear/disappear between checking the if condition and executing either task. Generally you proceed with task A as if the file is there and handle the exception if it turns out to not be there. File I/O is a form of concurrency and you should assume that things can change between any two program statements.

Answer (score 0):

Python optimizer is pretty stupid by design, but this is one case that the optimizer happens to be capable of detecting:

```
>>> def a():
...     if foobar:
...         pass
... 
>>> dis.dis(a)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (foobar)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        9

  3           6 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 9)
        >>    9 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE      
>>> def b():
...     if not foobar:
...         pass
... 
>>> dis.dis(b)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (foobar)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE         9

  3           6 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 9)
        >>    9 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

For which you should use, write readable code rather than worrying about little details like this.